# Call function when items are added or removed from a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm writing a widget kit for the Nano-X window system. In my base class `view`, I have a vector defined:

```
std::vector<RSMKit::View *> children;
```

Is it possible to call a function (`GrReparentWindow` in this case) when an item is added or removed from the vector so that the newly added widget can be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Do not inherit from `std::vector`. Just encapsulate it.

```
template<typename T> struct MyVector
{
private:
    std::vector<T> items;
public:
    void push_back (const T& x)
    {
        // Do something here
        items.push_back(x);
    }
    // etc
};
```

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. You also should not subclass `std::vector` to overwrite `push_back` and `erase`, because the class has not been designed for it. However, it would be simple to write your own container that would use `std::vector` for storage and expose `Add` and `Remove` functions with callbacks. Something along the following lines:

```
template<typename T>
class CallbackVector
{
public:

    typedef void (*Callback)();

private:

    std::vector<T> elements;
    Callback       OnAdd;
    Callback       OnRemove;

public:

    CallbackVector(Callback OnAdd, Callback OnRemove)
        : OnAdd    (OnAdd)
        , OnRemove (OnRemove)
    {
    }

    void Add(const T & element)
    {
        elements.push_back(element);
        OnAdd();
    }

    void Remove(int i)
    {
        elements.erase(elements.begin() + i);
        OnRemove();
    }
};
```

In practice, you would probably want a more complicated callback, using a function with a pointer parameter or using `boost::function`.

Comment: Simplest is best for the sake of the example. Other callback implementations have their pros and cons.

Comment: What the hell could he possibly implement in a free function with no arguments? You're basically forcing him to use global variables to actually do anything in his callback. That's a deal-breaking con. `boost::function` might not be the fastest thing in the universe, but it's far from global-variables in the scheme of "Incredibly bad, design-destroying things to do.".

Comment: I am not forcing him to do anything. This is not what the example is about. Normally, one would want the functions to at least take a "this" parameter, but the overhead would distract from the point. I would be careful about recommending boost to a beginner.

Comment: Might as well use function pointer with arguments and context. BTW, I often use private inheritance and using directive to handle similar tasks.

Comment: Boost would probably be out of the question since this is for an embedded system with a slow processor and about ~2-4 MB RAM available after the OS has booted.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to subclass your vector class and add callbacks on the insertion and removal methods. With an stl vector this is not possible by default

Comment: Standard containers are not meant to be subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways;

(1) Inherit `std::vector` and overload `push_back()` and `pop_back()` method:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyVector : std::vector<T>
{
  void push_back (const T& x)
  {
    GrReparentWindow ();
    vector<T>::push_back(x);
  }
  // same way pop_back()
};
```

Usage:

```
MyVector<RSMKit::View*> children;
children.push_back(new RSMKint::View);
```

(2) Another way is to `push_back` the items with custom overloaded operator or method; if you are allowed to edit `RSMKit::View`

```
class RSMKit::View
{
//...
public:
  RSMKit::View* get ()
  {
    GrReparentWindow ();
    return this;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
MyVector<RSMKit::View*> children;
RSMKit::View *p = new RSMKint::View;
children.push_back(p->get());
```